# Issue to add a 1px space btw 4 DIVs l

Tags: html, css

I have 4 divs ( each one 25% width) within another DIV (.block). The issue is that I want a 1px space to separate each DIV so the solution that I've found is to add a margin-left of 1px to DIVs 2, 3 and 4. So now I have 25% * 4 + 3px which means the last DIVs goes under the other ones. Is there another way to do what I'm trying to achieve?
Thanks

http://jsfiddle.net/ymE8R/

[image]

```
<div class="block">
    <div class="col1 c1">dsqd</div>
    <div class="col2 c2">sdsqdss</div>
    <div class="col3 c3">sdqsdsq</div>
    <div class="col4 c4">sdsqd</div>
</div>

.block {
    background: red;
    width:90%;
    Height: 200px;
}
.col1, .col2, .col3, .col4 {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    background: red;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 300;
    height: 24px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
}
.c1 {
    background: #253151;
}
.c2 {
    background: #253151;
    border-left: 1px #FFF solid;
}
.c3 {
    background: #253151;
    border-left: 1px #FFF solid;
}
.c4 {
    background: #253151;
    border-left: 1px #FFF solid;
}
```

Comment: You can use `box-sizing` - http://jsfiddle.net/ymE8R/1/

Comment: Thanks. It worked! Can you put this as an answer so that I can accept it? Also would you know why my text is not vertically-aligned despite the fact that I used vertical-align: middle; and display: table-cell;? Many thanks

Comment: also, in modern browser you can use width: calc(25% - 1px);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `width:25%; border-left:1px solid #fff;` and with that add this

```
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

**[Live demo here (click).](http://jsbin.com/oJAmUjA/1/edit)**

Comment: Yeah, that's better. I added a live demo for you :)

Comment: Indeed what I would do as well. I was making a fiddle for my answer already, but there is no real point in answering now, so here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/ymE8R/7/

Comment: for firefox -moz is required, and if you don't want that white border for first block, you can do that using first-child thing in css

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to  make the `width: 24.5%` and `margin-left: .5%`

Answer (score 1):

Solutions are `box-sizing` or the hack by @m59 if you want to use `percent` if you want the margin  to be in `px` use [calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) check http://caniuse.com/calc

Answer (score -1):

Try This:

Use below code in your CSS

```
.block div:last-child{
    width:24.3%;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -2):

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
       <style>
        .block {
        background: red;
        width:100%;
        Height: 200px;
        }
        * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        .col1, .col2, .col3, .col4 {
        float: left;
        width: 25%;
        background: red;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 12px;
        color: #fff;
        font-weight: 300;
        height: 24px;
        vertical-align: middle;
        display: table-cell;
        }
        .c1,.c2,.c3,.c4 {/*use class selector grouping*/
        background: #253151;
        }
        .c2,.c3,.c4 {/*use class selector grouping*/
        border-left: 1px #FFF solid;
        }
       </style>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div class="block">
        <div class="col1 c1">dsqd</div>
        <div class="col2 c2">sdsqdss</div>
        <div class="col3 c3">sdqsdsq</div>
        <div class="col4 c4">sdsqd</div>
    </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

[image]